# Load Javascript into ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load

I am new to working with AJAX and have some experience with Java/Jquery. I have been looking around for an solution to my problem but i cant seem to find any.

I am trying to build a function in a webshop where the product will appear in a popup window instead of loading a new page.

I got it working by using this code:

```
$(".product-slot a").live('click', function() {
  var myUrl = $(this).attr("href") + " #product-content";
  $("#product-overlay-inner").load(myUrl, function() {
  });
  $("#product-overlay").fadeIn();
  return false;
});
```

product-slot a = Link to the product in the category page.
product-content = the div i want to insert in the popup from the product page.
product-overlay-inner = The popup window.
product-overlay = The popup wrapper.

The problem that i now have is that my Javascript/Jquery isnt working in the productpopup. For example the lightbox for the product image or the button to add product to shoppingcart doesnt work. Is there anyway to make the javascript work inside the loaded content or to load javascript into the popup?

I hope you can understand what my problem is!

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT: The platform im using has jquery-ui-1.7.2**

Comment: You probably need to rebind the Lightbox function, or the 'add product to basket' handler, to the new content you've added (when it runs, it only binds to the content that exists at that point). If you can add in the code where that happens initially, that should help give a more accurate answer.

Comment: Yes you can do it, but you cannot use `load`. I found `load` strips out Javascript. You need to use a `get` and do a little manipulation to get the Javascript to act is if it was run `onload`

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread but I've been working on a similar process with the same script loading problem and thought I'd share my version as another option.

I have a basic route handler for when a user clicks an anchor/button etc that I use to swap out the main content area of the site, in this example it's the ".page" class.

I then use a function to make an ajax call to get the html content as a partial, at the moment they are php files and they do some preliminary rendering server side to build the html but this isn't necessary.

The callback handles placing the new html and as I know what script I need I just append it to the bottom in a script tag created on the fly. If I have an error at the server I pass this back as content which may be just a key word that I can use to trigger a custom js method to print something more meaningful to the page.

here's a basic implementation based on the register route handler:

```
var register = function(){
    $(".page").html("");
    // use the getText ajax function to get the page content:
    getText('partials/register.php', function(content) {
        $(".page").html(content);
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = "js/register.js";
        $(".page").append(script);
    });
};




/******************************************
 * Ajax helpers
 ******************************************/
// Issue a Http GET request for the contents of the specified Url.
// when the response arrives successfully, verify it's plain text
// and if so, pass it to the specified callback function
function getText(url, callback) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", url);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        // if the request is complete and was successful -
        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
            // check the content type:
            var type = request.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
            if (type.match(/^text/)) {
                callback(request.responseText);
            }
        }
    };
    // send it:
    request.send(null); // nothing to send on GET requests.
}
```

I find this a good way to 'module-ize' my code into partial views and separated JavaScript files that can be swapped in/out of the page easily.
I will be working on a way to make this more dynamic and even cache these 'modules' for repeated use in an SPA scenario.

I'm relatively new to web dev so if you can see any problems with this or a safer/better way to do it I'm all ears :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can load Javascript from a dynamic page, but not with `load()` as `load` strips any Javascript and inserts the raw HTML.

Solution: pull down raw page with a `get` and reattach any Javascript blocks.

Apologies that this is in Typescript, but you should get the idea (if anything, strongly-typed TypeScript is easier to read than plain Javascript):

```
    _loadIntoPanel(panel: JQuery, url: string, callback?: { (): void; })
    {
        // Regular expression to match <script>...</script> block
        var re = /<script\b[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/gm;
        var scripts: string = "";
        var match;

        // Do an async AJAX get
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "get",
            success: function (data: string, status: string, xhr)
            {
                while (match = re.exec(data))
                {
                    if (match[1] != "")
                    {
                        // TODO: Any extra work here to eliminate existing scripts from being inserted
                       scripts += match[0];
                    }
                }

                // Replace the contents of the panel
                //panel.html(data);

                // If you only want part of the loaded view (assuming it is not a partial view)
                // using something like
                panel.html($(data).find('#product-content'));

                // Add the scripts - will evaluate immediately - beware of any onload code
                panel.append(scripts);

                if (callback) { callback(); }
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error)
            {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    }
```

### Plain JQuery/Javascript version with hooks:

It will go something like:

```
    var _loadFormIntoPanel = function (panel, url, callback) {
        var that = this;
        var re = /<script\b[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/gm;
        var scripts = "";
        var match;
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "get",
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                while(match = re.exec(data)) {
                    if(match[1] != "") {
                        // TODO: Any extra work here to eliminate existing scripts from being inserted
                        scripts += match[0];
                    }
                }
                panel.html(data);
                panel.append(scripts);
                if(callback) {
                    callback();
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    };

$(".product-slot a").live('click', function() {
    var myUrl = $(this).attr("href") + " #product-content";
    _loadFormIntoPanel($("#product-overlay-inner"), myUrl, function() {
         // Now do extra stuff to loaded panel here
    });
  $("#product-overlay").fadeIn();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I am having trouble translating this inte my code. My skills in Javascripts are too low. I know this is much to ask but do you think you can translate it to my code so i can paste it into the code i mentioned in the start of the thread?

Comment: @sebbur: I have pasted a Javascript equivalent. Hopefully no typos as I did can't check easily the whole example with your code. Good luck :)

Comment: Aah a big thanks to you for your help! Now i am almost there :) The only problem now is that the ajax loads in the entire page instead of just the div "#product-content" and the scripts. Is there anyway to fix that? Or should i in some way remove the elements that i dont want?

Comment: Simple: `panel.html($(data).find('#product-content'))`. I will adjust answer to match

Comment: Ah, perfect! I added a script to the code but it appends "object [HTMLScriptElement]". What i did was that I replaced `var scripts = "";` from your code with: 
`var productID = $(this).parents(".product-slot").attr('data-product-id');
var scripts = document.createElement('script');
scripts.setAttribute('src', '/js/product/' + productID);
scripts.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');`

Should i do it some other way?

Comment: The code above was intended to work with inline javascript and not javascript src=includes. It was assumed you will have any libraries already loaded, but if your fix works for `src=` files, go for it :)

Comment: Ah ok! :) Unfortunately the scripts still gets stripped with the code :( I put a <script>-source inside the #product-content but it gets removed when its loaded via Ajax. I dont know what to do.

Comment: Use Fiddler2 (www.telerik.com/fiddler) to check what is returned by the Ajax call... The code above was used in a production project from about 12 months ago, so should still work.